# Webpage crashes on mobile after interacting with Iframe with Three.js

Tags: javascript, iframe, mobile, three.js

I have a modal that contains an Iframe that utilises Three.js to load a 3d Door.

The Iframe works fine on desktop top however, when we interact with it on mobile, it crashes or reloads the page when we close the modal. On safari the page reloads but on the second reload it crashes the page

**Page Loading the Iframe**

`<iframe loading="lazy" id="door-viewer" src="<?= "{$site_url}/3d-spinner.php?sku={$unique_skus[0]}"; ?>" sandbox></iframe>`

**File which generates iframe**

```
<?php 
   $product_sku = isset($_GET['sku']) ? strtoupper($_GET['sku']) : null;

    $proto = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'];
    $name = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

    $site_url = "{$proto}://{$name}";
?>
<?php
    header("Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' ".file_get_contents(getcwd()."/3d-spinner-assets/allowed-domains.txt").";");
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Three JS CDN Scripts -->
        <script async src="https://unpkg.com/es-module-shims@1.6.3/dist/es-module-shims.js"></script>
        <script type="importmap">
        {
            "imports": {
            "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.155.0/build/three.module.js",
            "three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.155.0/examples/jsm/"
            }
        }
        </script>
        <!-- IFRAME STYLES -->
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            canvas {
                object-fit: cover;
                width: 100% !important;
                height: 100% !important;
                aspect-ratio: 1;
                background-image: radial-gradient(at 50% 50%, rgb(245, 245, 245) 20%, rgb(206, 206, 206) 90%);
            }

            .lpd-360-image-icon {
                position: absolute;
                top: 2rem;
                left: 2rem;
            }

            #door-viewer {
                position: relative;
            }

            noscript {
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-self: center;
                font-size: 2rem;
                height: 100vw;
                width: 100vw;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <noscript>
            Please enable JavaScript and reload your browser
        </noscript>
        <?php if($product_sku) : ?>
            <div id="door-viewer">
                <!-- Canvas is injected via Three.js -->
            </div>
        <?php else : ?>
            <div>
                <p>Product not found, check your sku</p>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <script type="module">
            const sku = "<?= preg_replace('/[^-a-zA-Z0-9_]/', '', $product_sku ); ?>"
            const site_url = "<?= $site_url; ?>"

            import initSpinner from "./3d-spinner-assets/assets/scripts/main.js"

            initSpinner(sku, site_url);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Main.js File**

```
import * as THREE from "three";
import { GLTFLoader } from "three/addons/loaders/GLTFLoader.js";
import { OrbitControls } from "three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js";

function initSpinner(sku, site_url) {
      const doorAssetPath = `${site_url}/3d-spinner-assets/door/${sku}/model.gltf"`;
      const doorViewerCanvas = document.getElementById("door-viewer");

      // Scene
      const scene = new THREE.Scene();

      // Camera
      const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, 500 / 500, 0.1, 800);
      camera.position.z = 10;
      camera.position.y = 0;
      camera.position.x = 0;

      // Renderer
      const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        antialias: true,
        devicePixelRatio: 1,
        alpha: true,
      });
      renderer.setSize(1200, 1200); // Set Scene Size
      renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
      renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 0); // Make scene transparent
      renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio); // Set Pixel Ratio in line with device

      // Scene Lighting
      const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040, 90);
      scene.add(ambientLight);

      // Controls
      const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
      controls.enableDamping = true; // Add damping for smoother motion
      controls.dampingFactor = 0.05; // Adjust the damping factor
      controls.rotateSpeed = 0.5; // Adjust rotation speed
      controls.zoomSpeed = 1.2; // Adjust zoom speed

      // Load Door
      const loader = new GLTFLoader();
      loader.load(doorAssetPath, (gltfScene) => {
        const loadedDoor = gltfScene.scene;

        // Traverse the loadedDoor to set transparency for the windows
        const windowMaterials = []; // Add the window materials to this array

        // Inside the load callback function
        loadedDoor.traverse((child) => {
          if (
            (child.isMesh && child.name === "glass") ||
            child.name === "Glass"
          ) {
            const windowMaterial = child.material;
            windowMaterial.transparent = true;
            windowMaterial.opacity = 0; // Adjust opacity value
            windowMaterials.push(windowMaterial);
          }
        });

        const scaleFactor = 0.003; // Adjust this value as needed
        loadedDoor.scale.set(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, scaleFactor); // Adjust door's scale 
        loadedDoor.position.setY(-3); // Offset door's position
        scene.add(loadedDoor); // Add the door to the scene
      });

      doorViewerCanvas.appendChild(renderer.domElement); // Mount canvas to the DOM

      function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        controls.update(); // Update the controls
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
      }

      animate();
}

export default initSpinner;
```

I have had a look for a memory leak but unable to find anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, the canvas was loading around 3000px wide on mobile. I had to update the html to include

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

and update the main.js file to get the width and height from the window

```
  // Camera
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    75,
    window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
    0.1,
    800
  );
  camera.position.z = 5;
  camera.position.y = 0;
  camera.position.x = 0;

  // Renderer
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true,
    devicePixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio,
    alpha: true,
  });
```